# Running Scripts Before and After Suspend with Systemd

Tags: systemd, suspend, scheduling

I found [this blog article here](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/) that explains the process of Running scripts before and after suspend with systemd. Here are the steps:

1. Create a `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/suspend-date.sh` script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want before suspend here, e.g.:
  echo "we are suspending at $(date)..." > /tmp/systemd_suspend_test
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want after resume here, e.g.:
  echo "...and we are back from $(date)" >> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test
fi
```

2. Provide execute permission:

```bash
chomd +x /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/suspend-date.sh
```

3. Suspend the PC
4. Awaken the PC
5. View the log of what happend

```bash
nano /tmp/systemd_suspend_test
```

**But,** when I get to step 5 nothing happens. The `systemd_suspend_test` file is never created, hence - there's nothing to view.

My troubleshooting is:

- Confirm the script has appropriate permissions:

```
[/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep]$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 317 Sep 19 14:31 suspend-date.sh
```

- In terminal issue the command to confirm it's working:

```
echo "we are suspending at $(date)..." > /tmp/systemd_suspend_test && \
echo "...and we are back from $(date)" >> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test
```

and view the `/tmp/systemd_suspend_test` file:

```
we are suspending at Wed 20 Sep 2023 02:25:28 PM EDT...
...and we are back from Wed 20 Sep 2023 02:25:28 PM EDT
```

- Restart the sleep system

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-sleep
Failed to restart systemd-sleep.service: Unit systemd-sleep.service not found.
```

How do I get my `suspend-date.sh` script to launch when my computer goes into and out of suspend, as it should when placed in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` directory?

Comment: Hi, you probably should add the PATH like `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin` on the 2nd line. Check my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1318782/497758 
Btw, the blog article is poorly written.

Comment: Does `journalctl -b -u systemd-suspend.service` show any failures?